# Import Azure Time Series Insights data into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-timeseries-insights

We were implementing the Azure Time Series insights(TSI) for the data streaming through IoT hub and wanting to connect to Power BI for advanced visualization. There is a provision to build a custom query to connect to Power BI from Azure TSI but i guess there is a limitation of fetching a dataset for specific time frame and only for the time series ID selected for the view.

Is there a way we can get the latest data in Power BI as and when the data refreshes in Azure TSI and for additional number of time series ID which were not selected while building the query.

Cheers,

Amit

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a query from TSI to feed into Power BI, you can manually edit it to include the TSIDs you want to see. If you set the "isSearchSpanRelative" parameter to true, the data should refresh in Power BI as it comes into TSI.